# Android Studio fails - unsupport unsupported major minor version 51.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Until yesterday my Android Studio was working fine and helping me to create Applications. But today, it started giving Gradle error error stating unsupport major minor version 51.0 and asking me to configue gradle.

I get the same error if I try to import the project back.

[image: gradle error]

My java version is 7 and older Android projects in the Android studio work properly.

```
$ /usr/bin/java -version 
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=utf8 
java version "1.7.0_07" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
(build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)
```

How do I solve my gradle problem with android-studio?

Comment: What do you see in the log? I don't know the details, but it seems that somehow your project is using JDK 6 with classes compiled with JDK 7.

Comment: Could not find anything specific in the log.

Comment: What do you see in "About" dialog? It should tell you which JRE is used to run the IDE.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Last night Google team pushed version 0.7.2 of the Gradle plugin.
This version requires Java7. This is a mistake.

The plugin 0.7.3 will fix it.

You can switch back from 0.7.+ to 0.7.1 in your plugin, until 0.7.3 will be available from Maven Central.

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.1'
        }
```

Comment: where will I find this setting this android studio?

Comment: In build.gradle files inside your project.

Comment: Thanks!. I solved by reinstalling the studio and it was fine. But if  it misbehaves again, I know where to look for. It is now:     dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }

Comment: Pay attention: plugin 0.6.+ works with gradle 1.8 (you can find the version used in your project in gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties).
Gradle 1.9 requires plugin 0.7.1 or 0.7.3.