# Problems with Gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I had to reinstall Android Studio and now when I try to build my projects I get this error:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.
```

I tried editing system variables and Android Studio settings but nothing has seemed to work.

Andrew

Comment: Does this answer help you?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796827/android-studio-fails-unsupport-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/20797553#20797553

Comment: Great, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the Android plugin v0.7.2 and will be fixed in 0.7.3. In the meantime you can force it back to 0.7.1 following the answer here:

[Android Studio fails - unsupport unsupported major minor version 51.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20796827/android-studio-fails-unsupport-unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0/20797553#20797553)