# Gradle error when pressing "run app" - Android Studio 0.4.3 [ Could not create an instance of Tooling API ]

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting this error when I press "run app". I been searching for a fix the last two days, can you help me?

I have Android Studio 0.4.3 installed, this issue started when my school update Java on my school computer.

> org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip'.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        defaultFlavor {
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

This did not solve the issue:

- [Problems with Gradle in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20820707/problems-with-gradle-in-android-studio)

Comment: please include your all `build.gradle` files in the question.

Comment: I only found one build.gradle file :)

Comment: ok. Also check  Help > About to confirm on which version of JRE Studio is running ?

Comment: It says JRE:1.7.0_51-b13 x86

Comment: Check in File > Project Structure > Android SDK, is it also pointing to your jdk 1.7 directory ?

Answer (score 1):

Close Android Studio, take a backup and delete all these files from your studio setup directory and start it again, might be it can help you

```
android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-0.6.1.jar
android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-model-0.6.1.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-build-setup-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-plugins-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
```

Let me know if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: It gave me 57 errors, what should I do after deleting those files?

Comment: sync your project with gradle from studio or clse studio and open it again.

Comment: I can't because I get this error:

NoClassDefFoundError: update failed for AnAction with ID=AndroidConnectDebuggerAction: com/android/builder/model/SourceProvider

Comment: It solved the problem for many as my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213487/cannot-inherit-from-final-class/21213727#21213727

Comment: I have 19 reputation and I need 20 to chat :(

Comment: ok give me your email id, let me send you the latest file that you need to replace in firectory.

Comment: Yes, but I'm currently reinstalling Android Studio. I have 24 reputation now, but I still can't chat...

Comment: Ok, The problem is with gradle 1.7 you should have all files like `builder-model-0.7.0` so make sure after installing it again. Cheers !!

Comment: Are you still having problems or have you figured it out?