# Execution failed for process app:dexDebug after adding BaseGameUtils

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services, leaderboard

I just imported baseGameUtils to my android game in order to add a Google play Leaderboard however, when I press play I get this error: `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2`

I tried following the instructions from these two pages: [Stackoverflow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460443/execution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process-proces), [Stackoverflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330021/gradle-error-when-pressing-run-app-android-studio-0-4-3-could-not-create-a).
I tried setting the google support libraries to 22.2.1 and 8.1.0 in the basegameutils build.gradle, but then I get missing dependencies in the .java files in that library.

I'm all out of ideas and in need of help.
Thank you all in davance.

app:build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.honeycomb.touchtycube"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 11
    versionName "1.1.6"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//compile project(':facebook');


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.1.0'
compile project(':BaseGameUtils')

//compile project(':libs:basegameutils')
//compile 'com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk:AdBuddiz-Java:3.0.15'
compile files('src/main/java/com/honeycomb/touchtycube/testapp/libs/AdBuddiz-3.0.15.jar')

}

repositories {
    maven {
       url 'http://repository.adbuddiz.com/maven'
    }
}
```

BaseBuildUtils:build_gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'


buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}


}

dependencies {
// Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
if (!hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
    ext.appcompat_library_version = '20.0.+'
}
if (!hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
    ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
}
if (!hasProperty('gms_library_version')) {
    ext.gms_library_version = '7.8.0'
}
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${appcompat_library_version}"
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:${gms_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${gms_library_version}"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:${gms_library_version}"
}

android {
// Set defaults so that BaseGameUtils can be used outside of BasicSamples
if (!hasProperty('android_compile_version')) {
    ext.android_compile_version = 20
}
if (!hasProperty('android_version')) {
    ext.android_version = '20'
}

compileSdkVersion android_compile_version
buildToolsVersion android_version
}
```

EDIT:
I can do a "make Project" without any errors, the errors only appear when I do a "run app" (Or well I guess it's technically "run 'configuration'").

Comment: Its multi dex error please post fill error log.

Comment: @JaykishanSewak I don't really understand what you mean :/

Answer (score 0):

Check you prograud rules once. Also add your gradle build file.

Comment: What do you mean with checking my prograud rules?